# Time Served shows 0.0us in goaccess tool

Tags: nginx, analyzer, goaccess

We installed GoAccess v0.9 in our linux machine. we have customized log format in nginx.

```
log_format  timed_combined  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" <msec=$msec|connection=$connection|connection_requests=$connection_requests|millis=$request_time>';
```

But while viewing logs using goaccess tool, Time served parameter shows 0.00us for all the panels. Log format used in goaccess.conf is

```
log-format %h %^[%d:%^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" %^ %D
```

How to display the correct time served in Goaccess report

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your `log-format` is correct, Nginx uses milliseconds, so instead of specifying `%D` (microseconds), you should use `%T`.

```
log-format %h %^[%d:%^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" %^ %T
```

More about [custom log](http://goaccess.io/man#custom-log).

Comment: You may want to use `%t`, it appears it was introduced in v0.9. `%h %^[%d:%t %^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" %^ %T`